# Z-order on Java Swing components

Tags: java, swing, components, z-order

I've been looking all over for some mention of this, but I cannot find any substantial information on it. Is there a way to change the z-order of Swing components, or at least change the draw order so that they appear to be above others?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for [setComponentZOrder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29)

Here's an [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20120615230436/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/01/21/swing-internals-paint-order).

Comment: Oh wow. I even seached for z-order specifically, and nothing came up. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to overlay components over other components, you should use [JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html), which will let you add components to specific layers. This is precisely what's used for things like tooltips and drag-and-drop operations.

Here's a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the setComponentZOrder(...) method of the Container class.

You can also check out the [Overlap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) which has a brief description on how ZOrder works.