# How to show the buttons,which are hidden behind the background image?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I have added a background image to a Frame but when i add buttons they just hides behind the image,i am using `NullLayout` for the Frame.Please help me how can i get my button upfront the background image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229638/z-order-on-java-swing-components See if that helps.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead [use layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: `I have added a background image to a Frame` how? Are you doing custom painting? Did you add a label with an icon? We are not mind readers. You should always post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with your question that demonstrates the problem so we don't have to guess what you are doing. So update your question with a proper SSCCE and has already been stated, don't user a null layout. If you want the button to display you add the button to a panel that does use a layout manager.