# How can i access one component over another using mouselistener

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I have two or more j components. I want to place one component over the other by dragging the mouse and placing it over it.

While placing the component label 2 over label 1 the component label 2 must tell that it is placed over label 1. 
Similarly all components must tell on which component it is placed.

Comment: Hi, can you show us what you have done?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for Z-Indexing of components. There's another question related to this with links to examples. Here: [Z-order on Java Swing components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229638/z-order-on-java-swing-components)